# how can I completely turn off ftp with proftp?

Tags: proftpd

I only want to use SFTP and turn off FTP for my proftp server. I don't want to "Limit LOGIN", but turn it off completely. I also tried to turn off the DefaultServer, but this way the server still answers.

What I want is the response "ftp: connect: Connection refused". How can I configure proftp this way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't possible https://github.com/proftpd/proftpd/issues/822

EDIT:
This actually is possible through setting the FTP port to 0.

Comment: To expand on this: setting `Port 0` in server config isn't enough, you'll also need to use the Port directive in each VirtualHost to ensure nothing is listening on 21.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is another way that for me looks more clean:

- Disable the default server (DefaultServer off)
- and create vhost(s) for the services you want to offer.

Comment: To expand on this: in the VirtualHost config you'll need to use the Port directive for each, otherwise any without will by default use port 21.